# other term for Linq-Where

Tags: c#, linq

In my `C# linq-Querys` i often use an expression like (a rule in my app):

```
.Where(x => x.Id == 1 || x.Id == 12 || x.Id == 16)
```

Can I write this in a CustomExpression like:

```
.MyIdCheck()
```

Or is there a better way, to encapsulate the rule?

Comment: `.Where(x => new[] { 1, 12, 16 }.Contains(x))` . A **HashSet** for `new[] { 1, 12, 16 }` would be even better.

Comment: The answer depends greatly on the type of LINQ you're dealing with. A SQL backend makes it totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare an extension method for types that `IEnumrable<T>`:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public IEnumerable<T> MyIdCheck(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        return input.Where(x => x.Id == 1 || x.Id == 12 || x.Id == 16);
    }
}
```

In place of `T` you have to place the type of your object.

Then you can use it as you use the `Where`.

```
var result = input.MyIdCheck();
```

Another approach it would be to define an array, that holds the Ids you are looking for, like below:

```
var ids = new int[] { 1, 12, 16 };
```

Then your check it would be like below:

```
var result = input.Where(x=>ids.Contains(x));
```

Comment: You would need 'where T : SomeTypeWhichHasId' constraint

Comment: @CRice, for this reason I mentioned in place of `T`, we place the type that OP needs to do the check, If there are many types that has an Id property and we want exactly the same logic, then we should place this extra constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a method:

```
private bool MyIdCheck(int x) {
    return x.Id == 1 || x.Id == 12 || x.Id == 16
}

// ...

.Where(x => MyIdCheck(x.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var acceptableIds = new List<int>() {1, 12, 16};
```

Then use the contains function on the list.

```
a.Where(x => acceptableIds.Contains(x.Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the lambda expression reusable by making a named method out of it:

```
public static bool MyIdCheck(MyClass x) {
  return x.Id == 1 || x.Id == 12 || x.Id == 16;
}
```

Now you can use the method name where you would use the lambda expression:

```
.Where(MyIdCheck)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Func:

```
Func<MyClass, bool> MyIdCheck = x => x.Id == 1 || x.Id == 12 || x.Id == 16;
```

And call it like:

```
var allMyClass = new List<MyClass>();
Console.WriteLine(allMyClass.Where(MyIdCheck));
```

Or add this to your class:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyClass> MyIdCheck(IEnumerable<MyClass> myClass)
{
    return myClass.Where(x => x.Id == 1 || x.Id == 12 || x.Id == 16);
}
```

And call it like:

```
MyClass.MyIdCheck(allMyClass);
```